# armazenar dois pedaços de uma string em duas outras strings

Tags: c

Basicamente oq eu preciso é fazer um mini simulador de assembly.
as informações serão introduzidas pelo usuario assim: **MOV A,30**

aí oq eu tava pensando em fazer era armazenar os 3 primeiros caracteres da string em uma nova string (que no caso seria o primeiro comando "MOV") e armazenar a parte de **"A,30"** em outra, para depois separar essa ultima string e obter os outros 2 comandos, mas quando eu digito o comando, apenas os 3 primeiros caracteres (MOV) são mostrados no print.

alguem sabe como eu poderia fazer pra dar certo oq eu estou fazendo, ou como eu poderia apenas separar as 3 informações e armazená-las, sem a necessidade de separá-la?

Aqui está a base desse código:

```
int main()
{
    char comando[20];
    char comando1[20];
    char comando2[20];
    char comando3[20];
    scanf("%s", &comando);

    memcpy(comando1, &comando[0], 3);

    memcpy(comando2, &comando[3], strlen(comando));

    printf("\n%s %s", comando1, comando2); // essa parte aq é só pra verificar se foi armazenado corretamente

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Sua leitura tá errada. `%s` vai parar no primeiro espaço em branco.
2. Você tá copiando memória em variáveis não inicializadas que supostamente serão strings, vai dar problema.
3. Se você sabe que a primeira string será de apenas 3 caracteres, então a segunda deveria começar da posição 4, pois a posição 3 é um espaço em branco.

```
int main()
{
    char comando[20];
    char comando1[20] = "";
    char comando2[20] = "";
    char comando3[20];
    scanf("%[^\n]", &comando); //aqui vai ler até o primeiro \n

    memcpy(comando1, &comando[0], 3);

    memcpy(comando2, &comando[3], strlen(comando));

    printf("\n%s %s", comando1, comando2); // essa parte aq é só pra verificar se foi armazenado corretamente

    return 0;
}
```

Mas... Se levar em consideração o que eu falei em `1.`... Você poderia fazer simplesmente:

```
int main()
{
    char comando2[20];
    char comando3[20];
    scanf("%s %s", comando2, comando3);
}
```

Comment: Apenas complementando: caso o início de sua string não tenha obrigatoriamente 3 caracteres você pode quebrar sua string utilizando a função `strtok` de `<string.h>`.

Comment: bom, melhor que usar o strtok pra quebrar no espaços é já ler separado conforme sugeri no final.

Comment: Para este caso específico sim. Só quis chamar a atenção para o fato de que já existe uma função para dividir uma string em tokens.

Comment: eu tava fazendo isso de ler os 2 comandos separados, mas tambem não estava dando certo, então eu imaginei que fosse porque na digitação do comando não há um ENTER para diferir um do outro, apenas um espaço, então o programa iria ler os 2 comandos como apenas 1, pq o espaço seria lido como um dos caracteres.

obg pela ajuda!!